# Change output based on value in xsl:key in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, muenchian-grouping

I have a fairly large (270mb) XML file that I need to group, sort, and run multiple transforms on.

**Input XML:**

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<EligibilityRecords xmlns="http://Eligibility_LSDD">
  <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
    <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID></PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <PT_LST_NM>VALLE</PT_LST_NM>
    <PT_FRST_NM>FRANKIE</PT_FRST_NM>
    <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
    <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
    <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID></DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID></DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <DP_RELATIONSHIP></DP_RELATIONSHIP>
  </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
  <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
    <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>123456</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <PT_LST_NM>BULLOCK</PT_LST_NM>
    <PT_FRST_NM>SANDRA</PT_FRST_NM>
    <EN_PLAN_NAME></EN_PLAN_NAME>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
    <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
    <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID></DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID></DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <DP_RELATIONSHIP></DP_RELATIONSHIP>
  </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
  <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
    <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <PT_LST_NM>DOE</PT_LST_NM>
    <PT_FRST_NM>JANE</PT_FRST_NM>
    <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
    <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
    <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID></DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID></DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <DP_RELATIONSHIP></DP_RELATIONSHIP>
  </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
  <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
    <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>610051908</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <PT_LST_NM>JACKSON</PT_LST_NM>
    <PT_FRST_NM>MICHAEL</PT_FRST_NM>
    <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
    <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
    <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>610051908</DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>NC110015202761</DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <DP_RELATIONSHIP>Spouse</DP_RELATIONSHIP>
    <DP_LST_NM>JACKSON</DP_LST_NM>
    <DP_FRST_NM>MELISSA</DP_FRST_NM>
  </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
  <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
    <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>561859010</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <PT_LST_NM>MCLEOD</PT_LST_NM>
    <PT_FRST_NM>CONOR</PT_FRST_NM>
    <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
    <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
    <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>561859010</DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>SC000018241906</DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <DP_RELATIONSHIP>Dependent</DP_RELATIONSHIP>
    <DP_LST_NM>MCLEOD</DP_LST_NM>
    <DP_FRST_NM>DUNCAN</DP_FRST_NM>
  </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
  <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
    <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>573794953</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <PT_LST_NM>GABRIEL</PT_LST_NM>
    <PT_FRST_NM>PETER</PT_FRST_NM>
    <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
    <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
    <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID></DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID></DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <DP_RELATIONSHIP></DP_RELATIONSHIP>
  </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
  <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
    <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <PT_LST_NM>DOE</PT_LST_NM>
    <PT_FRST_NM>JANE</PT_FRST_NM>
    <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
    <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
    <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>NC110012077673</DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <DP_RELATIONSHIP>Spouse</DP_RELATIONSHIP>
    <DP_LST_NM>DOE</DP_LST_NM>
    <DP_FRST_NM>JOHN</DP_FRST_NM>
  </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
  <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
    <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <PT_LST_NM>DOE</PT_LST_NM>
    <PT_FRST_NM>JANE</PT_FRST_NM>
    <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
    <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
    <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>NC110012077680</DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <DP_RELATIONSHIP>Dependent</DP_RELATIONSHIP>
    <DP_LST_NM>DOE</DP_LST_NM>
    <DP_FRST_NM>JIMMY</DP_FRST_NM>
  </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
  <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
    <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <PT_LST_NM>DOE</PT_LST_NM>
    <PT_FRST_NM>JANE</PT_FRST_NM>
    <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
    <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
    <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>NC110012077681</DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <DP_RELATIONSHIP>Dependent</DP_RELATIONSHIP>
    <DP_LST_NM>DOE</DP_LST_NM>
    <DP_FRST_NM>JESSICA</DP_FRST_NM>
  </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
</EligibilityRecords>
```

**I have the following requirements:**

1. Strip all Eligibility_Detail_Records that have a blank PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID AND The EN_PLAN_NAME node is not "Health Reimbursement Arrangement" or "Health Savings Account"
2. Create a new Dependent_Record that is a child record of Eligibility_Detail_Record for each DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID that matches a PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID
3. Add an EN_PLAN_TYPE field for each Record that has an EN_PLAN_NAME of "Health Reimbursement Arrangement" that reads:

   - "Ind" if no dependents are found
   - "IndSpouse" if one and only one dependent that has DP_RELATIONSHIP of Spouse
   - "IndChild" if one and only one dependent that has DP_RELATIONSHIP of Dependent
   - "Family" if more than one dependent
4. Add an EN_HDHP_COVERAGE_LEVEL field for each Record that has en EN_PLAN_NAME of "Health Savings Account" that reads:

   - "Ind" if no dependents are found
   - "Family" if one or more dependents are found

**Expected XML output:**

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EligibilityRecords xmlns="http://Eligibility_LSDD">
  <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
    <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <PT_LST_NM>DOE</PT_LST_NM>
    <PT_FRST_NM>JANE</PT_FRST_NM>
    <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
    <EN_PLAN_TYPE>Family</EN_PLAN_TYPE>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
    <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
    <Dependent_Record>
      <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>NC110012077673</DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <DP_RELATIONSHIP>Spouse</DP_RELATIONSHIP>
      <DP_LST_NM>DOE</DP_LST_NM>
      <DP_FRST_NM>JOHN</DP_FRST_NM>
    </Dependent_Record>
    <Dependent_Record>
      <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>NC110012077680</DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <DP_RELATIONSHIP>Dependent</DP_RELATIONSHIP>
      <DP_LST_NM>DOE</DP_LST_NM>
      <DP_FRST_NM>JIMMY</DP_FRST_NM>
    </Dependent_Record>
    <Dependent_Record>
      <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>NC110012077681</DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <DP_RELATIONSHIP>Dependent</DP_RELATIONSHIP>
      <DP_LST_NM>DOE</DP_LST_NM>
      <DP_FRST_NM>JESSICA</DP_FRST_NM>
    </Dependent_Record>
  </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
  <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
    <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>610051908</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <PT_LST_NM>JACKSON</PT_LST_NM>
    <PT_FRST_NM>MICHAEL</PT_FRST_NM>
    <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
    <EN_PLAN_TYPE>IndSpouse</EN_PLAN_TYPE>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
    <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
    <Dependent_Record>
      <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>610051908</DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>NC110015202761</DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <DP_RELATIONSHIP>Spouse</DP_RELATIONSHIP>
      <DP_LST_NM>JACKSON</DP_LST_NM>
      <DP_FRST_NM>MELISSA</DP_FRST_NM>
    </Dependent_Record>
  </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
  <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
    <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>561859010</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <PT_LST_NM>MCLEOD</PT_LST_NM>
    <PT_FRST_NM>CONOR</PT_FRST_NM>
    <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
    <EN_PLAN_TYPE>IndChild</EN_PLAN_TYPE>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
    <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
    <Dependent_Record>
      <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>561859010</DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>SC000018241906</DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <DP_RELATIONSHIP>Dependent</DP_RELATIONSHIP>
      <DP_LST_NM>MCLEOD</DP_LST_NM>
      <DP_FRST_NM>DUNCAN</DP_FRST_NM>
    </Dependent_Record>
  </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
  <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
    <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>573794953</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <PT_LST_NM>GABRIEL</PT_LST_NM>
    <PT_FRST_NM>PETER</PT_FRST_NM>
    <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
    <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
    <EN_PLAN_TYPE>Ind</EN_PLAN_TYPE>
  </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
  <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
    <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>561859457</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
    <PT_LST_NM>BUGLE</PT_LST_NM>
    <PT_FRST_NM>MAN</PT_FRST_NM>
    <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Savings Account</EN_PLAN_NAME>
    <EN_HDHP_COVERAGE_LEVEL>Family</EN_HDHP_COVERAGE_LEVEL>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
    <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
    <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
    <Dependent_Record>
      <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>561859457</DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>SC000018241906</DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <DP_RELATIONSHIP>Dependent</DP_RELATIONSHIP>
      <DP_LST_NM>BUGLE</DP_LST_NM>
      <DP_FRST_NM>BOY</DP_FRST_NM>
    </Dependent_Record>
  </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
</EligibilityRecords>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var" version="1.0" xmlns:ns0="http://Eligibility_LSDD" xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
  <xsl:key name="ParticipantGroup" match="Eligibility_Detail_Record" use="PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID" />
  <xsl:key name="DependentSearch" match="Eligibility_Detail_Record" use="DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/ns0:EligibilityRecords" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/ns0:EligibilityRecords">
    <ns0:EligibilityRecords>
      <xsl:for-each select="set:distinct(Eligibility_Detail_Record/PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID)/..">
        <xsl:if test="PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID != '' and (EN_PLAN_NAME = 'Health Reimbursement Arrangement' or EN_PLAN_NAME = 'Health Savings Account')">
          <Eligibility_Detail_Record>
            <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
              <xsl:value-of select="PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID/text()" />
            </PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
            <PT_LST_NM>
              <xsl:value-of select="PT_LST_NM/text()" />
            </PT_LST_NM>
            <PT_FRST_NM>
              <xsl:value-of select="PT_FRST_NM/text()" />
            </PT_FRST_NM>
            <EN_PLAN_NAME>
              <xsl:value-of select="EN_PLAN_NAME/text()" />
            </EN_PLAN_NAME>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="EN_PLAN_NAME = 'Health Reimbursement Arrangement'">
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="key('DependentSearch',DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID) != ''">
                    <xsl:choose>
                      <xsl:when test="count(key('DependentSearch',DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID)) &gt; 1">
                        <EN_PLAN_TYPE>Family</EN_PLAN_TYPE>
                      </xsl:when>
                      <xsl:when test="count(key('DependentSearch',DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID)) = 1">
                        <xsl:choose>
                          <xsl:when test="DP_RELATIONSHIP = 'Spouse'">
                            <EN_PLAN_TYPE>IndSpouse</EN_PLAN_TYPE>
                          </xsl:when>
                          <xsl:otherwise>
                            <EN_PLAN_TYPE>IndChild</EN_PLAN_TYPE>
                          </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                      </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <EN_PLAN_TYPE>Ind</EN_PLAN_TYPE>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="EN_PLAN_NAME = 'Health Savings Account'">
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="count(key('DependentSearch',DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID)) &gt; 0">
                    <EN_HDHP_COVERAGE_LEVEL>Family</EN_HDHP_COVERAGE_LEVEL>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <EN_HDHP_COVERAGE_LEVEL>Single</EN_HDHP_COVERAGE_LEVEL>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
              </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
              <xsl:value-of select="EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT/text()" />
            </EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
            <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
              <xsl:value-of select="EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT/text()" />
            </EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
            <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
              <xsl:value-of select="EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT/text()" />
            </EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('ParticipantGroup',PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID)">
              <xsl:if test="DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID/text()">
                <Dependent_Record>
                  <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID/text()" />
                  </DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
                  <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID/text()" />
                  </DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
                  <DP_RELATIONSHIP>
                    <xsl:value-of select="DP_RELATIONSHIP/text()" />
                  </DP_RELATIONSHIP>
                  <DP_LST_NM>
                    <xsl:value-of select="DP_LST_NM/text()" />
                  </DP_LST_NM>
                  <DP_FRST_NM>
                    <xsl:value-of select="DP_FRST_NM/text()" />
                  </DP_FRST_NM>
                </Dependent_Record>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ns0:EligibilityRecords>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am fairly green at XML but I am using a Muenchian Grouping to create the Dependent Groups under the appropriate parent record and then had the idea to create another key for the **DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID**, then count how many occurrences of that key there are to determine what the **EN_PLAN_TYPE** or **EN_HDHP_COVERAGE_LEVEL** should be.

All of my requirements are met and everything is working with the exception of that **EN_PLAN_TYPE** code. Even that almost works correctly.

It outputs **IndSpouse**, **IndChild**, and Family correctly when those criteria are met but when there are no dependents for a particular parent record it still outputs Family in the **EN_PLAN_TYPE node**.

My assumption is that when you create an **xsl:key** it will put empty values in the key-value pair for each one and I thought I was testing for that properly but apparently I am not.

I will take any and all advice on how to make any of this code more readable/efficient/what have you. Such as using templates to remove the unwanted nodes from the result set rather than using an **xsl:if**. But the major concern I have right now is getting the correct output into the **EN_PLAN_TYPE** node.

The engine I am using is actually the BizTalk 2010 Mapper and I do have access to ESXLT (which I am already making use of for the Muenchian Grouping)

Comment: TL,DR. If you have a "major concern", then concentrate on that and minimize the example code to only what's necessary to demonstrate it - see: [mcve]. Ask your other questions separately.

Comment: Edited for Brevity. Thanks @michael.hor257k

Comment: Rolled the question back so the accepted answer makes more sense to future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is based on your original, more detailed, requirements:

> 1. Strip all Eligibility_Detail_Records that have a blank PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID AND The EN_PLAN_NAME node is not "Health
>      Reimbursement Arrangement" or "Health Savings Account"
> 2. Create a new Dependent_Record that is a child record of Eligibility_Detail_Record for each DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID that
>      matches a PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID
> 3. Add an EN_PLAN_TYPE field for each Record that has an EN_PLAN_NAME of "Health Reimbursement Arrangement" that reads:
>
>    - "Ind" if no dependents are found
>    - "IndSpouse" if one and only one dependent that has DP_RELATIONSHIP of Spouse
>    - "IndChild" if one and only one dependent that has DP_RELATIONSHIP of Dependent
>    - "Family" if more than one dependent
> 4. Add an EN_HDHP_COVERAGE_LEVEL field for each Record that has en EN_PLAN_NAME of "Health Savings Account" that reads:
>
>    - "Ind" if no dependents are found
>    - "Family" if one or more dependents are found

I started to look at your original XSLT (before the edit for brevity), but I think it was a little more complicated than it needed to be and that made it harder to determine what the problem was with generating the `EN_PLAN_TYPE`.

Here are a few suggestions:

- Just use a single `xsl:key` for all participants based on the `PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID` that ties them all together.
- Since you're not making any changes to the content of most elements, instead of creating new elements and using `xsl:value-of` to output the text(), just copy the original element using `xsl:copy-of`.
- For the bigger pieces of logic, like determining `EN_PLAN_TYPE`/`EN_HDHP_COVERAGE_LEVEL`, create named templates you can call (or you could apply-templates).

Here's an example. Determining the `EN_HDHP_COVERAGE_LEVEL` for `Health Savings Account` hasn't been tested since there wasn't an example in the input.

**XML Input**

```
<EligibilityRecords xmlns="http://Eligibility_LSDD">
    <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
        <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID></PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <PT_LST_NM>VALLE</PT_LST_NM>
        <PT_FRST_NM>FRANKIE</PT_FRST_NM>
        <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
        <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
        <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
        <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
        <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID></DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID></DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <DP_RELATIONSHIP></DP_RELATIONSHIP>
    </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
    <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
        <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>123456</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <PT_LST_NM>BULLOCK</PT_LST_NM>
        <PT_FRST_NM>SANDRA</PT_FRST_NM>
        <EN_PLAN_NAME></EN_PLAN_NAME>
        <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
        <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
        <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
        <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID></DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID></DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <DP_RELATIONSHIP></DP_RELATIONSHIP>
    </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
    <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
        <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <PT_LST_NM>DOE</PT_LST_NM>
        <PT_FRST_NM>JANE</PT_FRST_NM>
        <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
        <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
        <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
        <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
        <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID></DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID></DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <DP_RELATIONSHIP></DP_RELATIONSHIP>
    </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
    <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
        <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>610051908</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <PT_LST_NM>JACKSON</PT_LST_NM>
        <PT_FRST_NM>MICHAEL</PT_FRST_NM>
        <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
        <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
        <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
        <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
        <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>610051908</DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>NC110015202761</DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <DP_RELATIONSHIP>Spouse</DP_RELATIONSHIP>
        <DP_LST_NM>JACKSON</DP_LST_NM>
        <DP_FRST_NM>MELISSA</DP_FRST_NM>
    </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
    <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
        <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>561859010</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <PT_LST_NM>MCLEOD</PT_LST_NM>
        <PT_FRST_NM>CONOR</PT_FRST_NM>
        <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
        <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
        <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
        <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
        <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>561859010</DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>SC000018241906</DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <DP_RELATIONSHIP>Dependent</DP_RELATIONSHIP>
        <DP_LST_NM>MCLEOD</DP_LST_NM>
        <DP_FRST_NM>DUNCAN</DP_FRST_NM>
    </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
    <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
        <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>573794953</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <PT_LST_NM>GABRIEL</PT_LST_NM>
        <PT_FRST_NM>PETER</PT_FRST_NM>
        <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
        <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
        <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
        <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
        <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID></DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID></DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <DP_RELATIONSHIP></DP_RELATIONSHIP>
    </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
    <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
        <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <PT_LST_NM>DOE</PT_LST_NM>
        <PT_FRST_NM>JANE</PT_FRST_NM>
        <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
        <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
        <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
        <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
        <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>NC110012077673</DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <DP_RELATIONSHIP>Spouse</DP_RELATIONSHIP>
        <DP_LST_NM>DOE</DP_LST_NM>
        <DP_FRST_NM>JOHN</DP_FRST_NM>
    </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
    <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
        <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <PT_LST_NM>DOE</PT_LST_NM>
        <PT_FRST_NM>JANE</PT_FRST_NM>
        <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
        <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
        <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
        <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
        <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>NC110012077680</DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <DP_RELATIONSHIP>Dependent</DP_RELATIONSHIP>
        <DP_LST_NM>DOE</DP_LST_NM>
        <DP_FRST_NM>JIMMY</DP_FRST_NM>
    </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
    <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
        <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <PT_LST_NM>DOE</PT_LST_NM>
        <PT_FRST_NM>JANE</PT_FRST_NM>
        <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
        <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
        <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT></EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT>
        <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
        <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>NC110012077681</DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
        <DP_RELATIONSHIP>Dependent</DP_RELATIONSHIP>
        <DP_LST_NM>DOE</DP_LST_NM>
        <DP_FRST_NM>JESSICA</DP_FRST_NM>
    </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
</EligibilityRecords>
```

**XSLT 1.0** (requirements are added as comments)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="participants" match="Eligibility_Detail_Record" use="PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!--Strip all Eligibility_Detail_Records that have a blank PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID AND The EN_PLAN_NAME node is not "Health Reimbursement Arrangement" or "Health Savings Account"-->
      <xsl:for-each select="Eligibility_Detail_Record[string(PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID) and (EN_PLAN_NAME='Health Reimbursement Arrangement' or EN_PLAN_NAME='Health Savings Account')]
        [count(.|key('participants',PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID)[1])=1]">
        <xsl:variable name="participantCount" select="count(key('participants',PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID))"/>
        <Eligibility_Detail_Record>
          <xsl:copy-of select="*[starts-with(name(),'PT_')]|EN_PLAN_NAME"/>
          <xsl:choose>
            <!--Add an EN_PLAN_TYPE field for each Record that has an EN_PLAN_NAME of "Health Reimbursement Arrangement" that reads:-->
            <xsl:when test="EN_PLAN_NAME='Health Reimbursement Arrangement'">
              <xsl:call-template name="HRA">
                <xsl:with-param name="participantCount" select="$participantCount"/>
              </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <!--Add an EN_HDHP_COVERAGE_LEVEL field for each Record that has en EN_PLAN_NAME of "Health Savings Account" that reads:-->
            <xsl:when test="EN_PLAN_NAME='Health Savings Account'">
              <xsl:call-template name="HSA">
                <xsl:with-param name="participantCount" select="$participantCount"/>
              </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
          </xsl:choose>
          <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::EN_PLAN_NAME) and starts-with(name(),'EN_')]"/>
          <!--Create a new Dependent_Record that is a child record of Eligibility_Detail_Record for each DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID that matches a PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID-->
          <xsl:for-each select="key('participants',PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID)[string(DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID)]">
            <Dependent_Record>
              <xsl:copy-of select="*[starts-with(name(),'DP_')]"/>
            </Dependent_Record>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="HRA">
    <xsl:param name="participantCount"/>
    <EN_PLAN_TYPE>
      <xsl:choose>
        <!--"Family" if more than one dependent-->
        <xsl:when test="$participantCount > 1">Family</xsl:when>
        <!--"IndChild" if one and only one dependent that has DP_RELATIONSHIP of Dependent-->
        <xsl:when test="$participantCount = 1 and DP_RELATIONSHIP = 'Dependent'">IndChild</xsl:when>
        <!--"IndSpouse" if one and only one dependent that has DP_RELATIONSHIP of Spouse-->
        <xsl:when test="$participantCount = 1 and DP_RELATIONSHIP = 'Spouse'">IndSpouse</xsl:when>
        <!--"Ind" if no dependents are found-->
        <xsl:when test="$participantCount = 1">Ind</xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </EN_PLAN_TYPE>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="HSA">
    <xsl:param name="participantCount"/>
    <EN_HDHP_COVERAGE_LEVEL>
      <xsl:choose>
        <!--"Family" if one or more dependents are found-->
        <xsl:when test="$participantCount > 1 or
          $participantCount = 1 and string(DP_RELATIONSHIP)">Family</xsl:when>
        <!--"Ind" if no dependents are found-->
        <xsl:when test="$participantCount = 1">Ind</xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </EN_HDHP_COVERAGE_LEVEL>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<EligibilityRecords xmlns="http://Eligibility_LSDD">
   <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
      <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <PT_LST_NM>DOE</PT_LST_NM>
      <PT_FRST_NM>JANE</PT_FRST_NM>
      <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
      <EN_PLAN_TYPE>Family</EN_PLAN_TYPE>
      <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
      <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT/>
      <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
      <Dependent_Record>
         <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
         <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>NC110012077673</DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
         <DP_RELATIONSHIP>Spouse</DP_RELATIONSHIP>
         <DP_LST_NM>DOE</DP_LST_NM>
         <DP_FRST_NM>JOHN</DP_FRST_NM>
      </Dependent_Record>
      <Dependent_Record>
         <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
         <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>NC110012077680</DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
         <DP_RELATIONSHIP>Dependent</DP_RELATIONSHIP>
         <DP_LST_NM>DOE</DP_LST_NM>
         <DP_FRST_NM>JIMMY</DP_FRST_NM>
      </Dependent_Record>
      <Dependent_Record>
         <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>553739837</DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
         <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>NC110012077681</DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
         <DP_RELATIONSHIP>Dependent</DP_RELATIONSHIP>
         <DP_LST_NM>DOE</DP_LST_NM>
         <DP_FRST_NM>JESSICA</DP_FRST_NM>
      </Dependent_Record>
   </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
   <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
      <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>610051908</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <PT_LST_NM>JACKSON</PT_LST_NM>
      <PT_FRST_NM>MICHAEL</PT_FRST_NM>
      <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
      <EN_PLAN_TYPE>IndSpouse</EN_PLAN_TYPE>
      <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
      <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT/>
      <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012017</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
      <Dependent_Record>
         <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>610051908</DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
         <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>NC110015202761</DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
         <DP_RELATIONSHIP>Spouse</DP_RELATIONSHIP>
         <DP_LST_NM>JACKSON</DP_LST_NM>
         <DP_FRST_NM>MELISSA</DP_FRST_NM>
      </Dependent_Record>
   </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
   <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
      <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>561859010</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <PT_LST_NM>MCLEOD</PT_LST_NM>
      <PT_FRST_NM>CONOR</PT_FRST_NM>
      <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
      <EN_PLAN_TYPE>IndChild</EN_PLAN_TYPE>
      <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
      <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT/>
      <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
      <Dependent_Record>
         <DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>561859010</DP_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
         <DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>SC000018241906</DP_DEPENDENT_FILE_IMP_ID>
         <DP_RELATIONSHIP>Dependent</DP_RELATIONSHIP>
         <DP_LST_NM>MCLEOD</DP_LST_NM>
         <DP_FRST_NM>DUNCAN</DP_FRST_NM>
      </Dependent_Record>
   </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
   <Eligibility_Detail_Record xmlns="">
      <PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>573794953</PT_PARTICIPANT_FILE_IMP_ID>
      <PT_LST_NM>GABRIEL</PT_LST_NM>
      <PT_FRST_NM>PETER</PT_FRST_NM>
      <EN_PLAN_NAME>Health Reimbursement Arrangement</EN_PLAN_NAME>
      <EN_PLAN_TYPE>Ind</EN_PLAN_TYPE>
      <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_MBRSHP_EFF_STRT_DT>
      <EN_MBRSHP_EFF_END_DT/>
      <EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>01012016</EN_PLAN_YEAR_STRT_DT>
   </Eligibility_Detail_Record>
</EligibilityRecords>
```

Comment: Works terrifically. Shame I edited the original question before your answer came in. Thanks!

Comment: @Ritley572 - Glad I could help. I can roll back your question to a previous version so that it makes sense to future visitors.